# restrict user to record video for 3 seconds only in codename one

Tags: java, codenameone

I need recorded video from user in `codename one` am done with this. But I want to restrict user for not to record video of length more than `3 seconds`.

Is there any way to cut video after recording or can I stop recording after 3 second.

Answer (score 1):

i found this on another Thread, not experienced yet but this may help you.

```
Media = MediaManager.createMediaRecorder("filename.xyz", MediaManager.getMediaRecorderingMimeType());
Button doneButton = new Button("DONE");

doneButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            stopRecord(false);
        }
    });

   public void stopRecord(boolean timeElapsed)
   {
       answertiming.cancel();
       media.pause();
       media.cleanup();
       if(timeElapsed)
            Dialog.show("SUCCESS","Your time is up system has saved your answer, The file path for the recording is " + p, "OK",null);
       else
            Dialog.show("SUCCESS","You have successfully answered the question System has saved your answer, The file path for the recording is " + p, "OK",null);
   }
```

My approach now would be to put in a 3 second timer around this f.e.

```
UITimer timer = new UITimer(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 stopreRecord(true);
});
timer.schedule(3000, false, f);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to accomplish that in Codename One other than using the native interfaces functionality to integrate with the native OS http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html

Comment: if I use `nashorn` (`Javascript code in java`) CodenameOne will support ??? So I can code in javascript and use that functions in codename one.

Comment: We don't support nashorn. Since it runs in the JVM it would make no difference whatsoever. Codename One compiles to a native app so you have full access to the underlying native code and can do whatever you want.